# What is the Vulkan API version variant in VK_MAKE_API_VERSION?

Tags: version, specifications, vulkan

I just realized while using [`VK_MAKE_VERSION`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_MAKE_VERSION.html) that it has been deprecated. The deprecation message recommends using [`VK_MAKE_API_VERSION`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_MAKE_VERSION.html) instead. The only difference between them is that the latter has an additional `variant` parameter.

I know what the `major`, `minor`, and `patch` mean, but I never saw a `variant` version before. What does it mean?

Comment: While writing this question I realised that maybe I would find the answer in the spec, and I did, so I posted it here as it seems to be encouraged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in section [30.2.1. Version Numbers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/pdf/vkspec.pdf#page=934&zoom=100,0,790) of [the current Vulkan specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/pdf/vkspec.pdf):

> The Vulkan version number comprises four parts indicating the variant, major, minor and patch
> version of the Vulkan API Specification.
>
> The *variant* indicates the variant of the Vulkan API supported by the implementation. This is always
> 0 for the Vulkan API.
>
> > *Note*
> >
> > A non-zero variant indicates the API is a variant of the Vulkan API and
> > applications will typically need to be modified to run against it. The variant field
> > was a later addition to the version number, added in version 1.2.175 of the
> > Specification. As Vulkan uses variant 0, this change is fully backwards compatible
> > with the previous version number format for Vulkan implementations. New
> > version number macros have been added for this change and the old macros
> > deprecated. For existing applications using the older format and macros, an
> > implementation with non-zero variant will decode as a very high Vulkan version.
> > The high version number should be detectable by applications performing suitable
> > version checking.

Comment: Do you think a variant might be used to represent something like OpenGL vs OpenGLES then? A VulkanES or WebVk?

Comment: @Columbo It can't be OpenGL or OpenGLES as they are completely different from Vulkan. Why would anybody use an OpenGL flavor of Vulkan instead of just OpenGL? I understand that it could be something like "VulkanES" or "WebVk", though that seems to be against the cross-platform philosophy of Vulkan - the same Vulkan code can currently run on Windows, Android, and even Nintendo Switch. Why create a new, separate flavor of Vulkan? That's only speculation, though. It is possible that I just wasn't able to find any Vulkan variants and some exist or are planned.